# is there a way to edit unminified files and simultaneously bringing that change in minified CSS files too?

Tags: css, unminify

As it is known that its hard to edit the minified files and thus we prefer to edit minified files. Is there a way that the changes we make in unminified files are reflected in unminified files? Or is there a better technique to deal with this problem in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to edit the core bootstrap files which is what it sounds like, that's not a very good idea as it could have unforeseen impacts on the rest of your site.

It is far better to simply overwrite the bootstrap style that you want to change in your own css.

If you are talking about your own minified files, I would recommend getting a plugin for you text editor. I use brackets editor with this plug in https://github.com/abagshaw/brackets-minifier and whenever you save a CSS file you can do ctrl+alt+M to minify and overwrite your minified file. But all decent editors will have similar plugins available.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No worries mate :) happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to improve your workflow, you should check out some task automation command line tools. We use Gulp at my office. It automates makes those small, tedious, time-consuming tasks like minifying assets so that you can spend more time developing.